# Conflict between colortbl and \hrulefill

Tags: tables, incompatibility, colortbl

I define a new environment `\CCG` that takes two arguments (i.e. above and below texts) and an optional suffix.
I use `\hrulefill` to make sure that horizontal line fills the space before a suffix.

This solution seems to be messed up by `colortbl` package (e.g. when I use coloring a cell, for example).

[image: Without colortbl things are fine] [image: the line doesn't feel the space]

How I can use `colortbl` and still have the structure similar to `CCG`?
Manually encoding `\hrule` size is not a solution as CCG structures can be nested and length of texts can also vary.

MWE2 with nested structures:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcommand{\CCG}[3][]{
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\hspace{-3pt}}c@{\hspace{-3pt}}}
#2\\[-7pt]
\hrulefill\raisebox{-2.5pt}{\footnotesize{#1}}\\
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
        #3
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
}  

\begin{document}

\CCG[suffix]{\cellcolor{green}above text}{below text}
%\hspace{2cm}
%\CCG[suffix]{above text}{below text}
\vspace{5mm}

\CCG[$<$]{
    \CCG[$>$]{%
        \CCG{some}{$NP/N$}
        \CCG{man}{$N$}}
    {$NP$} 
    \CCG{run}{$S\backslash NP$}}
    {$S$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since `\CCG` content can be more arbitrary, could you provide some examples of these? How should the nesting preserve colour changes if nesting occurs in the "above text" part?

Comment: Sorry for unclear text. Let's say I just want to use `colortbl` with other tables not related to CCG. And forget about nesting. The two texts should be center aligned and a horizontal line+suffix filling the area between them (suffix is often one lettered).

Answer (score 2):

The comments in `colortbl.dtx` suggest that the author of the package, David Carlisle, *deliberately* changed first-order infinite glue (`fil`) around cells with second-order one (`fill`), in order “to dissuade people from putting stretch glue in table entries”.  You can easily see this glue with `\showlists`.

A possible, but horrible, workaround could be the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcommand{\CCG}[3][]{
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\hspace{-3pt}}c@{\hspace{-3pt}}}
#2\\[-7pt]
\leavevmode \leaders \hrule \hskip 0pt plus 1filll \kern 0pt % <<< change
    \raisebox{-2.5pt}{\footnotesize{#1}}\\
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
        #3
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
}  

\begin{document}

\CCG[suffix]{\cellcolor{green}above text}{below text}
\hspace{2cm}
\CCG[suffix]{above text}{below text}
% \showboxbreadth = 1000
% \showboxdepth = 10
% \showlists
\vspace{5mm}

\CCG[$<$]{
    \CCG[$>$]{%
        \CCG{some}{$NP/N$}
        \CCG{man}{$N$}}
    {$NP$} 
    \CCG{run}{$S\backslash NP$}}
    {$S$}

\end{document}
```

but I cannot accept any responsibility for anything this could break down inside the *colortbl* package! ;-)

**Edit**

Btw, here is the output:

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

I did the new environment with [calc](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/required/tools/calc.pdf) package for calculating widths of texts and then setting a size of `\rule` according to them.

Though the lines are nicely drawn (what I needed), cell coloring is bit messed.
But it works well outside the new environment.

**It would be helpful to know why the colors go outside the boundaries in the new environment.**

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\newccg}[3][]{%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\kern-1pt}c@{\kern-1pt}}
#2
\\[-1mm]
\rule[2.3pt]{\maxof{\widthof{#2}}{\widthof{#3}}-\widthof{#1}}{1pt}#1
\\[-1mm]
#3
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\newccg[$>>>$]{AA}{BBBBB}
~
\newccg[$<$]{CCCCCCCC}{DD}
~
\newccg[$<$]{
    \newccg[$>$]{%
        \newccg{\cellcolor{green}some}{$NP/N$}
        \newccg{man}{$N$}}
    {$NP$}
    \newccg{run}{\cellcolor{red}$S\backslash NP$}}
    {$S$}

\begin{tabular}{c | c}\hline
A & \cellcolor{red}A\\\hline
 \cellcolor{green}C & D\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```