# colortbl changes array behaviour

Tags: arrays, linguistics, colortbl

David Reiter passed the following code to me for generating CCG proofs. This works well provided one does not load `colortbl`.

Without `colortbl` I get:

[image]

and with `colortbl` I get:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Do the CCG poofs differently? I would like to use both packages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\deriv}[2]
{ %\arraycolsep=.25em
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.5}
  \ensuremath{\begin{array}[t]{@{}*{#1}{c}@{}}
     #2
   \end{array}} }

\newcommand{\hr}{\ensuremath{\hrulefill}}
\newcommand{\forwardapp}{\ensuremath{\hrulefill_{>}}}
\newcommand{\backwardapp}{\ensuremath{\hrulefill_{<}}}

\newcommand{\bs}{\char`\\}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\deriv{4}{
the  & cat & chased         & Mary\\
\hr  & \hr & \hr            & \hr \\
np/n & n   & (s\bs np)/np   & np\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{\forwardapp} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\forwardapp}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{{np}}             & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{{s\bs np}}\\
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{\backwardapp}\\
\multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{{s}}\\
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting, `colortbl` loads `array` which was changed recent ly. But loading just `array` does not give any problem.

Comment: @daleif this isn't a recent change, been that way since the 1980s:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so it's like that apparent 36 year old error that has just been "discovered" in `scp`?

Comment: @daleif I don't know about scp but this was a design choice, not an error.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/264067/15925

Comment: @AndrewSwann oh that's a duplicate and my answer here is same as GuM's, essentially

Comment: Funny, that this is about CCG as well. And I am reliefed that it was not me who asked this question earlier ... Thanks for the help! First did not notice the additional `l` ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the colortbl doc does warn against using infinite stretch in colortbl, so you need to squash it more strongly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%all the %% are needed...
\newcommand{\deriv}[2]
{%% %\arraycolsep=.25em
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.5}%%
  \ensuremath{\begin{array}[t]{@{}*{#1}{c}@{}}
     #2
   \end{array}}%%
 }

\def\hrulefilll{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\hskip 0pt plus 1filll\kern0pt }
\newcommand{\hr}{\ensuremath{\hrulefilll}}
\newcommand{\forwardapp}{\ensuremath{\hrulefilll_{>}}}
\newcommand{\backwardapp}{\ensuremath{\hrulefilll_{<}}}

\newcommand{\bs}{\char`\\}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\deriv{4}{
\mathrm{the}  & \mathrm{cat} & \mathrm{chased}  & \mathrm{Mary}\\ %math italic too painful
\hr  & \hr & \hr            & \hr \\
np/n & n   & (s\bs np)/np   & np\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{\forwardapp} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\forwardapp}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{{np}}             & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{{s\bs np}}\\
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{\backwardapp}\\
\multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{{s}}\\
}

\end{document}
```